# How to normalize an eigenvector with 2 parameters?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

example: x=t*(3,1,0)^T+s*(2/sqrt(2),0,1) How can I determine s and t, so that the length of the vector equals 1? I mean aren't there several pairs of possible solutions to this problem? If so, how can I express this fact in a mathematical way?

Comment: Yes, there will be multiple solutions. If you want to show specifically that there's more than one solution, you can just name two pairs of values for $t$ and $s$ so that $\|x\| = 1$. If you want to show infinitely many solutions, that's a bit trickier, and you'll need a parameterisation of the solutions in terms of some third parameter $\theta$ (indeed, there'll be an ellipse of solutions). But, before anyone launches into anything like that, some context would be good. I'm not convinced that whatever problem you're working on demands this kind work (given you mention eigenvectors).

Comment: I need to show all possible solutions. Its a classical mechanics exercise for undergrads in Germany, where one needs to determine the eigenvalues as well as the respective normalized eigenvectors of a given matrix

Comment: In that case, I would perform Gram-Schmidt on the vectors $(3, 1, 0), (\sqrt{2}, 0, 1)$ to obtain two orthonormal vectors $u_1, u_2$ with the same span. Then $\cos(\theta)u_1 + \sin(\theta)u_2$, where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ is a one-to-one parameterisation of the unit vectors formed by $x$, where $s$ and $t$ range over $\Bbb{R}$.